# Generating QR Codes in PNG and EPS instead of SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, next.js

I'm making a QR Code generator app. It provides QR Codes in SVG but I also want PNG and EPS options to be available (the API I use allows that)

Related code snippets:

```
type: req.query.type || "svg",

const [type, setType] = useState("");

const res = await axios.get("api/generate-qrcode/", {
    params: { input, size, backcolor, forecolor, type, setlabel, labeltext },
  });

<select
    className="text-primary text-base md:text-xs w-1/2 md:w-4/5 p-3 mt-4 mb-6 bg-secondary border-double border-b-4 border-b-primary border-r-4 border-r-primary rounded outline-none"
    onChange={(e) => setType(e.target.value)}
  >
    <option value="svg">SVG</option>
    <option value="png">PNG</option>
    <option value="eps">EPS</option>
</select>
```

My request sends type=png but I can't receive the QR code as the response. It works okay when I select SVG.

Response snippet:

```
{response && (
    <div className="mt-10 bg-primary">
      <SVG src={response} />
    </div>
```

I highly suspect the response code causes the error but I don't know how to fix it.

I tried this but didn't work:

```
{response && (
    <div className="mt-10 bg-primary">
      {type === "svg" && <SVG src={response} />}
      {type === "png" && <img src={`data:image/png;base64,${response}`} alt="QR Code" />}
    </div>
```

Also, on the top of the file, I have `import SVG from "react-inlinesvg";` to handle SVG. I did a research to see if I also need to import PNG, but documentations were stating it is not required.